# creating a complete array from different parts of strings and removing duplication in perl

Tags: arrays, excel

I am having an issue aain.
I think I am just tired, because my brain does not want to think anymore.
anyway.
I have multiple strings which I collect from a spreadsheet, each string has the same layout and I am searching for a specific part in the string. This is the easy part though. So the strings will look like this.

```
    this is a string from Japan
    this is a string from China
    this is a string from America
    this is a string from China
    this is a string from England
    this is a string from Japan
```

these strings are not local but I collect it from the excel sheet, so I am then calling to find the location of each string which is at the end, in this case I will take the viariable like this.

```
    use Spreadsheet::Read;
    my $book = ReadData ("INPUT.xlsx");
    my @rows = Spreadsheet::Read::rows ($book->[1]);

    my $count;
    $count = 0;

    my @clause_all;
    foreach my $tab(@rows) {

    $count ++;
    my @row = Spreadsheet::Read::cellrow ($book->[1], $count);
    print $row[5]; # $row[5] would be the location like "japan, china, america etc.
    }
```

Here is the part I am struggling though, the loop is seeing $row[5] as a single term, I need to now remove duplication and need to somehow join each line's $row[5] in order to get an array and then throw out the duplicates. I tried doing this, but it does not work due to the singular form of each $row[5]

```
    my %special = ();
    foreach (@my_array)
            {
    $special{$_} = 1;
            }
    my @deduped = keys %special;
    print "@deduped\n";
```

If I however create my own test array like this it works, besides for it throwing them out of the original order, anyway, so it MUST be a matter of getting locations $row[5] stored in array.

```
    @my_test_array = ("Japan", "China", "America", "China", "England", "Japan")
    my %special = ();
    foreach (@my_test_array)
            {
    $special{$_} = 1;
            }
    my @deduped = keys %special;
    print "@deduped\n";
```

Thanks in advance!

## --------------------------------

Edit!

## --------------------------------

Well, this did work, but not sure how neat this is. :)

```
    use Spreadsheet::Read;
    my $book = ReadData ("NSA_DB.xlsx");
    my @rows = Spreadsheet::Read::rows ($book->[1]);
    my $count;
    $count = 0;
    my @clause_all;
    foreach my $tab(@rows) {
        
        $count ++;
        my @row = Spreadsheet::Read::cellrow ($book->[1], $count);
    push @array, "$row[3]\n";
    }
    my %special = ();
    
     foreach (@array)
        {
         $special{$_} = 1;
          }
            my @deduped = keys %special;
             print "@deduped";
```

Thanks again.

Comment: `I tried doing this, but it does not work` We cannot diagnose problem only from "it does not work". Next time please provide any error messages or tell what expectations did you have and what really happened.

Comment: Move `%special` out of `@rows` loop?

Comment: Please read my updated answer. Hope it helps ;)

Answer (score 0):

It is not very clear from the question, but if you want to add only unique values to array in order these values appear in source spreadsheet:

```
my %added;
my @array;

for (whatever) {
    push @array, $_ unless exists $added{$_};
    $added{$_} = 1;
}
```

According to update on original question:

```
use Spreadsheet::Read;

my $book = ReadData ("NSA_DB.xlsx");
my @rows = Spreadsheet::Read::rows ($book->[1]);
my @array;
my %added;

for (my $count = 1; $count <= @rows; $count++) {
    my @row = Spreadsheet::Read::cellrow ($book->[1], $count);
    push @array, $row[3] unless $added{$row[3]};
    $added{$row[3]} = 1;
}

print join("\n", @array), "\n";
```

Comment: not quite, I want to extract the values that will be published elsewhere in XML format.